# Trying to loop a display of random numbers with javascript, cannot understand why only one number displays

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am attempting to write code that will eventually form the basis of a simple n-back game. Right now I am just trying to get 30 random numbers to display one after the other after a short delay (you may have seen my previous questions related to this little project--if so, thank you all for your input as it has been extremely helpful). I am able to loop the display exactly as I want it using a setInterval method, but this is no good because for some reason it will not accept a call-back function to track the numbers of intervals and then call the clearInterval method. In other words, the numbers continue to display indefinitely, which is not what I want. I am attempting to achieve the same thing instead using a function that makes use of a for-loop, but this won't work either because for some reason the function does not work correctly and only displays one random number then stops. See code below:

```js
var javascriptElement = "numbers-display";
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//This function takes a single argument and displays it in the browser.
function displayContent (content) {
  document.getElementById(javascriptElement).innerHTML = content;
};

function runRandomNumbers (array) {
  displayContent(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]);
};

function runOnTimeOut(fn, arg) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn(arg);
  }, 2000);
};

//this is the function that isn't doing what I want it to do.
function runOnLoop(fn, arg1, arg2) {
  for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    fn(arg1, arg2);
  };
}

runOnLoop(runOnTimeOut, runRandomNumbers, numbers);
```

```html
<div id="numbers-display"></div>
```

Is anyone able to point out why this function will only display one random number rather than 30 random numbers? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `await`ing promises in each iteration instead, else they'll all run at once (the `setTimeout`s are currently all triggering together, after 2000 ms):

```js
var javascriptElement = "numbers-display";
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//This function takes a single argument and displays it in the browser.
function displayContent (content) {
  document.getElementById(javascriptElement).innerHTML = content;
}

function runRandomNumbers (array) {
  displayContent(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]);
}

function runOnTimeOut(fn, arg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn(arg);
      resolve();
    }, 500)
  );
}

//this is the function that isn't doing what I want it to do.
async function runOnLoop(fn, arg1, arg2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    await fn(arg1, arg2);
  }
}

runOnLoop(runOnTimeOut, runRandomNumbers, numbers);
```

```html
<div id="numbers-display"></div>
```

Also note that `for` loop blocks *should not end* in semicolons, and neither should function declarations.

Comment: I'm learning a lot here. I think I need to read another book because I've never even seen the keywords you suggested. Thank you!